# In peer connection negotiation phase, is there ever a counter offer?

Tags: webrtc

So far, everything I've read on webrtc peer connections says that an "offer" is sent, and it is responded to with an "answer". Then the connection starts and all is well.

In my understanding, the offer is like "Hey, let's use this codec and encryption". Given that the answer always leads to a connection, it seems the answer is always "okay, let's use that!". Can there be a counter offer like "No, let's use this codec instead!". Who ultimately decides which settings are used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The offer contains a list of one side's acceptable codecs (prioritzed).
The answer contains the subset of those codecs, listing only the ones that both sides can do - possibly in a different order.

So: No the answer shouldn't contain a codec that wasn't in the offer.

But... Once Offer/Answer has happened, either side can send a second offer (this is typically used to add video to an existing audio-only session) and receive a new answer.

This means you could send an answer with no codecs and then send an second offer with a different set of codecs, but there is no reason to expect that the other side will change it's mind (unless there was some resource exhaustion)